# Cómo darle valor de forma dinámica a los atributos de los metadatos en php?

Tags: php, html

mi pregunta es acerca de cómo darle valor a los atributos de los metadatos con php.
Este es el codigo que tengo, pero en las búsquedas de google se ve mal:

```
<?php

$postController = new PostController();
$post = $postController->search($_GET['r']);
if (empty($post)) {
    $error = new ViewController();
    $error->load_view('404'); 
}else{
    $templatePost = 
    '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>'.$post[0]['titulo'].'</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="Description" content="'.$post[0]['subtitulo'].'" />
        <meta name="Keywords" content="'.$post[0]['keywords'].'"/>
        <meta name="distribution" content="global"/>
        <meta name="Robots" content="all"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/css/estilos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 640px)" href="./public/css/max-640px.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-141288874-1"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag("js", new Date());

          gtag("config", "UA-141288874-1");
        </script>
    </head>');
    print($templatePost);   
}
```

La metadata que muestra en el buscador, que no es la que yo quiero mostrar, es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La metadata description que tendría que aparecer es la siguiente:

content="Subtitulo de la prueba tres"

Comment: no creo que tu pagina tenga un ranking tan alto como para que google se moleste en escanearla cada 30 segundos. asi que te tocara esperar :v

Comment: Entonces es cuestion de tiempo hasta que ponga la descripcion correcta?

Comment: exacto! solo debes esperar! o puedes usar la herramiente index de google!

Comment: Si te referis a google search console, ya la use